# In syntax, why cannot we say things like "he took walked at the park"? but can say "he took a walk at the park"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntax

In syntax, why cannot we say things like

> "he took walked at the park"?

but can say things like

> "he took a walk at the park"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*A walk at the park* is essentially acting as a ***noun phrase*** where the word **walk** is not the verb **to walk** but the noun **walk** which is a *thing* that people do.

Therefore, in this whole sentence, there is only one verb: ***Took***. This verb takes the past tense of **take** to be **took.**

So, applying that knowledge to this sentence in particular:

> He ***took*** *a walk at the park*.
>   Subject(He) ***Verb*** *Object(noun phrase)*
>   agrees with English syntax

Comment: Of course, you could have said "he walked at the park" or perhaps better "he walked in the park"